# 'magic' value Device Driver

Tags: linux, driver, device

what is the 'magic' value in `tty_driver struct`

```
struct tty_driver {
   int     magic;          /* magic number for this structure */
   struct kref kref;       /* Reference management */
   struct cdev cdev;
   struct module   *owner;
   const char      *driver_name;
   ....
   ....
```

I don't understand why is it called 'magic'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magic numbers often refer to specific constants that identify a structure, file type or software. In this case, the tty_driver's magic number is apparently always defined like this:

```
#define TTY_DRIVER_MAGIC        0x5402
```

One practical use of the magic number in such a context might be to check the value of the first `sizeof(int)` bytes and make sure they `== 0x5402` before casting the rest of the received bytes into a `tty_driver struct`. In this respect, it might also be used to determine the appropriate byte ordering (little/big endian) for the rest of the header.