# What is the point of magic value?

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, device

what is the 'magic' value in tty_driver struct

```
struct tty_driver {
   int     magic;          /* magic number for this structure */
   struct kref kref;       /* Reference management */
   struct cdev cdev;
   struct module   *owner;
   const char      *driver_name;
   ....
   ....
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ['magic' value Device Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296469/magic-value-device-driver)

Comment: It's a "magic number" and used as a brief way to identify what kind of file or data or data structure one is looking at. It's just a unique identifier. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29 as a cross-reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* tty driver magic number */
#define TTY_DRIVER_MAGIC        0x5402
```

From tty_driver.h listing [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/marcelo/linux-2.4/include/linux/tty_driver.h).